# How can I update a table with if condition through SQL

Tags: sql

How could I set a query with ifs?
For example:

```
UPDATE users.users
SET usd = usd + '500'
```

The problem is that I need it work only to users where the column `unique_number` is not the same.

Comment: Please clarify `where the column unique_number is not the same`.

Comment: what do you mean by unique_number is not the same?

Comment: Not the same as what? You need to be clearer about your meaning.

Comment: The process if this , your register as many times u want. But if is same ip you get the same unique_number. I want to update only 1 of the accounts someone might have not all

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Those are two very different DBMS products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right you want to update users but only the first row for users with same IP addresses.

If you have an auto generated primary key column named id then the query will be

```
with cte as 
(
    select id,usd,unique_number, row_number()over (partition by unique_number 
    order by id) rn  from users.users 
)
UPDATE users.users SET usd = usd + '500' where rn=1
```

Above query will update users table with `usd = usd +'500'` if unique_number is single. If there are duplicate `unique_number`  then this query will update only the first occurrence.

** If usd is a number field use `usd = usd + 500` instead of `usd = usd + '500'`

Comment: Sorry if I didnt mention but unique_number is different for every user.  A random string

Comment: The process if this , your register as many times u want. But if is same ip you get the same unique_number. I want to update only 1 of the accounts someone might have not all

Comment: does user table has any unique id or primary key column?

Comment: Thanks kazi.  That's what I asked. Thank you

Comment: You are most welcome. Then please accept this answer by clicking the green check. Best wishes.